# How to fix problem with nested loop in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have encountered some problems with my loop. I have two variables which navigates to different childs of one table (both variables are list of elements). First variable navigates to names and second variable navigates to inputs. I want to click the particular input when the name of element from first variable is equal to certain word. The problem is that my second (nested) loop starts from first record while it should iterate until the condition is not made. Appreciate for advice. I'm new in selenium so maybe web elements works differently than other things.

```
sel = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table.table.table-condensed.table-top-spacing td[valign='top']")))
sel_input = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table.table.table-condensed.table-top-spacing input.nightlife_drug_quantity")))
    for s in sel:
        for i in sel_input:
            if s.text == "LSD":
                i.click()
                break
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-top-spacing"><thead><tr><th width="70%">Drug</th> <th width="10%">Stamina</th> <th width="10%">Price</th> <th width="20%">Buy</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td valign="top">Painkillers</td> <td>1%</td> <td>$23</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Booze</td> <td>2%</td> <td>$23</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Weed</td> <td>1%</td> <td>$19</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Magic mushrooms</td> <td>2%</td> <td>$27</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">LSD</td> <td>3%</td> <td>$15</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Ecstasy</td> <td>4%</td> <td>$15</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Cocaine</td> <td>7%</td> <td>$62</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Opium</td> <td>6%</td> <td>$37</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Amphetamine</td> <td>5%</td> <td>$70</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Heroin</td> <td>8.5%</td> <td>$43</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Hash</td> <td>2.5%</td> <td>$16</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Special K</td> <td>7.4%</td> <td>$55</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Morphine</td> <td>7.9%</td> <td>$46</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">GHB</td> <td>3.6%</td> <td>$22</td> <td nowrap="nowrap"><input name="quantity" type="text" maxlength="2" class="nightlife_drug_quantity"> <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-small">Buy</button></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant html so that other contributor might help you.

Comment: @KunduK Just edited and added the html

Comment: would you like to click on Buy button or enter text in the textbox?

Comment: @KunduK as mentioned above - I need to check td valign='top' text and if it is equal to 'LSD' then I want to click it's input

Comment: correct there is one input which is text and one button.so i guess you want to insert some value in input text rather click.or you want to click on buy button

Comment: @KunduK I will send the keys and click the button if I locate to desired input. I believe if I fiugre it out how to locate the input in the same row, I will locate button later on.

Comment: Added the the code.Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two for loops.Using **xpath** and `following` td or `following-sibling` td both will work.Try the below code.

```
sel = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='table table-condensed table-top-spacing']/tbody//tr//td[@valign='top']")))
for s in sel:
    if s.text=='LSD':
       s.find_element_by_xpath('./following::td/input[@name="quantity"]').click()
       s.find_element_by_xpath('./following::td/input[@name="quantity"]').send_keys("12")
       break;
```

Comment: Thanks :) I also just found another way - I use extra counter a = a + 1 and b = b+1. Also works but your code looks way better and elegant. Could you please explain me what ./folowing:: means ? Literally next td ?

Comment: It will check for a row if there any cell have the input tag. you can use either `following` or `following-sibling` both will work.